# android: add unique tag or id for spinner view

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I create 4 spinner views in my application, when I change the selected item on one of them I want to know which one of spinners is selected and changed. I use this code :

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
final Spinner spinner= new Spinner(context);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
                spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                    }
                });}
```

How can I set a unique tag for each spinner and return this tag on ItemSelectedListner? 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it:

```
 for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
   final Spinner spinner= new Spinner(context);
   spinner.setTag(i);
   ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
            spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                       if (parent.getTag().equals("0")){
                          //your code
                             }
                       else if (parent.getTag().equals("1")){
                          //your code
                              }

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parent.getId() in your onItemSelected() to get the Id of the spinner whose item is selected. The working code:

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){


final Spinner spinner= new Spinner(context);
   spinner.setId(i);
   ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
            spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                   switch(parent.getId()){
case "0": //your code
case "1": //your code
...
}

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: To set the id of each spinner, you can add a statement spinner.setId(i) in the loop.. This way each of your spinner gets a id on the go..

Comment: setid and getid return diffrent number